# Not opening share activity

Tags: android, share

I want to receive data from other apps. I have ShareActivity class and added it to AndroidManifest but i can't show my app to the share apps list. Please help.

```
<activity
        android:name=".share.ShareActivity"
        android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data
                android:host="www.youtube.com"
                android:mimeType="text/*"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

===============================  EDIT =======================================
Only i removed this line and it worked:

```
            <data
                android:host="www.youtube.com"
                android:mimeType="text/*"
                android:scheme="https" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specifies Your **`intent-filter`**  like below code

Try this

```
<activity android:name=".share.ShareActivity"  
    android:name=".share.ShareActivity"
    android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

for information **[read here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)**